# How to open a .pdf file, knowing only part of it's name

Tags: python, tkinter

I have pdf files inside a folder, I need to open a file by knowing only it's number.
The names are like: "TK20141 - Company name", So I need to open the file by only knowing the "20141".

```
import os
import subprocess

def otsi(x):
    leitud = []
    arr = os.listdir('C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov')
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if x in arr[i]:
            leitud.append(arr[i])
    return leitud

otsitav="33333"
print(otsi(otsitav))
subprocess.call(["xdg-open", otsi(otsitav)])
```

This code gives this error:

```
['TK33333 - Test.pdf']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Pooleli olev töö\Märkmed\import os.py", line 14, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["xdg-open", otsi(otsitav)])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 345, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1375, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 561, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to open all files at once in the last line. Since you're returning a list of file-names instead of a single file-name. So instead of calling `otsi` directly in the last line, store the return value and then call `xdg-open` for each string/name in the list.

Comment: Could there be more than one file with the value passed to *otsi()* in its name?

Comment: Use `pdf_file = glob.glob(f"C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/*{otsitav}*.pdf")` instead of listing all the files in the folder.  And I don't think `xdg-open` exists in Windows platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob.glob()` to find files using wildcard instead of listing all the files and then go through the file list to find the required files.

Also there is no `xdg-open` in Windows platform, use `os.startfile()` instead of `subprocess.call()`.

```py
import glob
import os

def otsi(x):
    return glob.glob(f'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/*{x}*.pdf')

otsitav="33333"
files = otsi(otsitav)
print(files)
if files:
    os.startfile(files[0])
```

Comment: how can I make it so that "otsitav" = user input? otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get() doesn't work.

Comment: It depends on how you get the *user input*.

Comment: Tellimus_entry = Entry(top2)
    Tellimus_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=(10, 10), sticky=(N, S, E, W), columnspan=3)

Comment: Use `otsitav = Tellimus_entry.get()`.  Note that it should be called after user has input something (normally by clicking a button after input).

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad sorry, I had it assigned to the wrong place.

Comment: when I run the program it automatically opens the first pdf file in the folder, and if I enter the input Tellimus_entry.get(), it says TypeError: otsi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: It is better to raise another question on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list as a parameter to xdg-open. If you only want to open the first PDF in the list, maybe try with:

```
subprocess.call(["xdg-open", otsi(otsitav)[0])
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your comment, I see that you need to provide the full path to the PDF file. Try this:

```
subprocess.call(["xdg-open", 'C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Proov/' + otsi(otsitav)[0])
```

Comment: This returns the error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Still returns the same answer

Comment: As @acw1668 mention probably the problem is that  there is no xdg-open in Windows

Comment: Yeah, the code @acw1668 provided works like a charm, thank you guys all! :)